# FlowRecordRelation object is fetching blank records

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

I have a process builder named inbound leads that will fire while creating marketing leads and i have included a time trigger within this process that will fire a flow to send an email to different teams if activities are not recorded under the respective lead.

Both process & scheduled flow are working as expected but the problem is if a rep wants to convert a lead within an hour they are facing an error like the **record is in another workflow**

So, i have checked the docs and included **$Flow.CurrentRecord** to attach the current lead recordid to the flow so we can identify which paused flow related to which record id.

But relatedrecordid object returning blank records. So I'm not sure how to identify paused flows

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$Flow.CurrentRecord is a system variable. You cannot set that it is set automatically as the records go through the system. You want something like:

```
myTextVariable = $Flow.CurrentRecord
```

Even better in the version properties Interview Label you can put what you want which you see in the paused interviews. This is where you want to put the $Flow.CurrentRecord variable. You would then not need the variable assignment you have. [image: Flow Version Properties screen]